# django filter by the chained foreignkey

Tags: django

Assuming there is code like below:

```
class A(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class B(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    a = models.ForeignKey(A)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class C(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    b = models.ForeignKey(B)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class X(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Y(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    x = models.ForeignKey(X)
    c = models.ForeignKey(C)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s(%s-%s)" % (self.name, self.x.name, self.c.name)
```

I want to filter against A to get all 'A's which the 'C' belong to A linked an instance of X (via Y). here is an example:

```
a1 = A.objects.create(name='A1')
a2 = A.objects.create(name='A2')

b11 = B.objects.create(name='B11', a=a1)
b12 = B.objects.create(name='B12', a=a1)

c111 = C.objects.create(name='C111', b=b11)
c112 = C.objects.create(name='C112', b=b11)
c113 = C.objects.create(name='C113', b=b11)

x1 = X.objects.create(name='X1')

y1 = Y.objects.create(name='Y1', x=x1, c=c111)
```

I want to filter on A to get the instance list which has 'x1' connected (via Y -> C -> B -> A), the expected result is [a1] in this example.

and if I continue to add:

```
b21 = B.objects.create(name='B21', a=a2)
c211 = C.objects.create(name='C211', b=b21)
y2 = Y.objects.create(name='Y2', x=x1, c=c211)
```

The expected result is [a1, a2].

Is there any easy way to do this?

Sorry, I find it a little hard for me explain that in English :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. Assuming `x1` is the instance of class `x`,

```
 a_results = A.objects.filter(b__c__y__x=x1) #or x__name if x1 is a string
```

Documentation [reverse lookups, and lookups that span relations](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)